# Diff command. Basic explanation

Tags: linux, diff

Just started with diff command. Can you please explain me,

```
diff thin_provisionings_controller.rb thin_provisionings_controller.rb[211]

512,513d511

   include ThinProvisioningsGraphModule
```

So does that says to delete lines 512, 513 and add 511?
As described by this article
http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-compare-files-diff.html

Comment: I recommend you use unified diffs (add `-u`).  They're easier to read and more resilient to unrelated changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `diff -y`, which stands for `diff --side-by-side`. It will show the output in two columns, one for each file. The columns will be in the same order you input the files on the command line.

Comment: Wow! I never knew about the `-y` option!

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video which will explain everything you want.

[image]